# How to provide view based access in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to give view based access in Jenkins. Is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by role-based access control in Jenkins. Please have a look at [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/).

Comment: We can't restrict it to a particular view though ( as I asked in the original question)